# is INR to USD conversion, Transformation or Translation?? In Websphere message broker?

Tags: message, transformation, broker

Presently I'm using IBM Integration Bus v9.0 and I have a doubt.
is INR to USD conversion, Transformation or Translation? please give me the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a technical question. It sounds as if there is something behind the question; maybe a contractual dispute? Please define your terms ( what do you mean by translation? ) and explain why you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Its translation, keep this in mind

Perform transformation on a message to make its structure comply with the receiving system’s requirements.

Perform data translation on a message so that its data is represented according to the receiving system’s conventions.

Simple translation might be required if the two systems use different values to represent the same information for a given field.

Complex translation might involve augmenting or replacing groups of fields with a completely different structure and encoding.

Money has a fixed value whether its in INR or USD, there's no structure to it but value with a unit, the unit is interpreted differently by different system, so its translation